Chat-UI v4.3.6 - NPE in PreChatActivityDelegate - termsAndConditionsContainer is null
I get a NPE on PreChatActivityDelegate class and this part seems to be the problematic  code:
View termsAndConditionsContainer = this.mPreChatActivity.findViewById(id.terms_and_conditions_container);
if (this.mPreChatTracker.displayTermsAndConditions()) {
    TextView termsAndConditions = (TextView)termsAndConditionsContainer.findViewById(id.terms_and_conditions);
    termsAndConditions.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    termsAndConditionsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    termsAndConditionsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

The exception indicates that termsAndConditionsContainer is null - so I'm wondering how can I ensure that termsAndConditionsContainer is correctly initialized?
